# cannot install anaconda on jetson agx xavier

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

[/home/aimotion/anaconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/aimotion/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
/home/aimotion/Downloads/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64 (1).sh: line 381: /home/aimotion/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/home/aimotion/Downloads/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64 (1).sh: line 383: /home/aimotion/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need aarch64 version.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux-aarch64/
Installers can be found: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

I took Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-aarch64.sh   487.7M  2021-11-17 12:08:43
with no problem